# SQL Server : set variables with an if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

I get two values passed from variables:

```
@F_START_DATE_DT VARCHAR(50)
@F_END_DATE_DT VARCHAR(50)
```

And I have other parameter declarated:

```
DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(4000)
```

I would like to **check if the first two variables are null** and do something like this but correctly:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @F_START_DATE_DT OR @F_END_DATE_DT IS NULL THEN 
SET @sSQL = 'select * from test_sql1'
ELSE
SET @sSQL = 'select * from test_sql2'
END
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Management

Comment: `null` and `''` are not same in tsql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that would suffice.

```
IF @F_START_DATE_DT IS NULL OR @F_END_DATE_DT IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @sSQL = 'SELECT * FROM test_sql1'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @sSQL = 'SELECT * FROM test_sql2'
    END
```

Comment: @rzry1911 I think yes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
SELECT 
    @sSQL = CASE 
                WHEN @F_START_DATE_DT IS NULL OR @F_END_DATE_DT IS NULL 
                   THEN 'select * from test_sql1'
                   ELSE 'select * from test_sql2'
            END
```

`CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** - it returns one of several possible values. It is **NOT** equivalent to a `switch {....}` statement in C# (or its equivalent in other programming languages) - it's **not** a flow control statement.

So basically you need to define your case conditions, and then return *one or another* value from your `CASE`.